# Can I save anything in the *-meta.xml file?

Tags: visualforce, metadata, eclipse

Every .page, .cls, etc... has a *-meta.xml file (at least as viewed from Eclipse).  Here is an example for a sample page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>27.0</apiVersion>
    <label>aaWsTester</label>
</ApexPage>
```

Is there a way I can save some extra information in this file?  The api says I can have a  key, but it won't save.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 5):

The metadata is the configurable parts of the page, class, etc, such as the version to use, etc. You can only store the values that are legal per [The Metadata API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf).

Comment: I wonder if you could cheat a bit and put any custom information in XML comments. Then the metadata would still be valid for Salesforce. It might however get wiped if Salesforce updates the Metadata file.